# How to find a string value at a given position and length

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I am preparing a testcase to test the values in a string response message I am getting from my webservice.

Example  string result = "-----1234-------DEV-------2014-03-30----44"

```
Field                     Length    position     Value
TRANS LENGTH                4          5          1234
TRANS DEST              7          9           DEV
TRANS ORGN              7          16          PROD
TRANS DATE              6          23          2014-03-30
TRANS ID                4          35          44
```

when I get a string response from the webservice,
I wanted to check if I can find value '1234' at positon 5 and of lenght 4.

Example:

```
Assert.AreEqual("TODO", TestContext.TRANSLENGTH);  TestContext.TRANSLENGTH.value(1234)
```

TODO: Here I want to check how I can find TRANS LENGTH from the incoming message using the position and length given above.
 once I find it I will assert if it is equal to what I am expecting.

Here is how I am reading the data from the specflow table:

```
public class SpecFlowData
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }



    public List<SpecFlowData> GetInputMessage(Table table)
    {

        var data = table.CreateSet<SpecFlowData>();
        var elements = (from item in data

                        select new SpecFlowData
                            {
                                Field = item.Field, 
                                Value = item.Value,
                                Position = item.Position,
                                Length = item.Length
                            }
                       ).ToList();
        return elements;
    }
```

EDIT: 
For example the response TRANS ID can be <=4 characters that's the maximum area allocated for the TRANS ID Field.

Let's say I have expected TRANS ID = 44 from the given table and the web service response TRANS ID is (result.Substring(35,4)). The test will not pass since the specflow table TRANS ID expecting 44 but not 44 and two spaces. How can assert such scenario? Thanks

Comment: What is the range of values that can be in that position. It sounds like you are using fixed length fields because your start is always 5. If so, look at the String.Substring method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: @MarkHall the position and length are fixed.I edited my original post.

Comment: Use Trim to remove your spaces. I would create an answer but am on my phone.

Comment: thanks actually i want to keep the spaces. I am trying to find a way to let specflow table allow me to add space when I read data from the tables so that specflow table will have a TRANS ID ="44  " which will be equal to the value i will be getting from result.Substring(35,4)

Comment: Is something like this what you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Rather than modifying the table with expected values, if you are happy with trailing spaces you can Trim the incoming response and only then do your assertions.